# Maximum value of $k!{m\brace k}$

Tags: combinatorics

Denote Stirling numbers of the second kind by ${m\brace k}$. For $m$ fixed,
what is the value $k_0$ of $k$ for which $k! {m\brace k}$ is maximal? I am interested in an asymptotic for $k_0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

(Is $k!{m\brace k}$ first increasing and then decreasing on $k$ for $m$ fixed?)

Comment: I saw in wiki it is said that the Stirling number of the second kind is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets and is denoted by ${m\brace k}$, so here the Stirling numbers of the second kind you mean is that one times $k!$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually meant. Edited.

Comment: If I read it correctly, then answer to your parenthetical question is yes by Cor. 3.1 by Masaaki Sibuya's paper "Log concavity of Stirling numbers and unimodality of Stirling distributions."

Comment: Not sure why this is true. I don't see $k! {m\brace k}$ mentioned there.

Comment: Let $b_k = k! S(m,k)$ (I don't know how to write Knuth's Stirling number notation in a way that is compatible with math jax, so I'm using $S(m,k)$).  That corollary (use the 3rd sequence with $a_k = k$ for $k \ge 2$) tells you $b_{k+1}/b_k$ is decreasing, so $b_{k+1}^2 \ge b_k b_{k+2}$.  That is, $(b_{k})$ is log concave, and therefore unimodal (increasing then decreasing).